# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type '() => void' of 'function result')

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, dart-pub

I am getting this error while debugging my flutter app , there is no error in my dart files but during debug I get this error . I am attaching my dart files here .

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:quiz_app2/quiz.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Quiz());
}
```

**quiz.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:quiz_app2/firstscreen.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app2/questions.dart';

class Quiz extends StatefulWidget {
  const Quiz({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Quiz> createState() {
    return _QuizState();
  }
}

class _QuizState extends State<Quiz> {
  Widget? activeScreen;

  @override
  void initState() {
    activeScreen = FirstScreen(switchScreen);
    super.initState();
  }

  void switchScreen() {
    setState(() {
      activeScreen = const QuestionScreen();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.deepPurple, Colors.deepPurpleAccent],
            ),
          ),
          child: activeScreen,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**firstScreen.dart**   <--  The error is showing at this file while debug .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen(this.startQuiz, {key}) : super(key: key);

  final void Function() startQuiz;
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/quiz-logo.png',
            height: 400,
            color: const Color.fromARGB(150, 250, 250, 250),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
            child: Text(
              'Learn Flutter the fun way!',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
          OutlinedButton.icon(
            onPressed: startQuiz,
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt),
            label: const Text(
              'Start Quiz',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**questions.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QuestionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuestionScreen({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuestionScreen> createState() {
    return _QuestionScreenState();
  }
}

class _QuestionScreenState extends State<QuestionScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return const Text('questions');
  }
}
```

I want the solution of this error , I have searched but not got the answer. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Does the debugger show you in what line the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    activeScreen = FirstScreen(switchScreen);
    super.initState();
  }
```

You do not seem to have `switchScreen` defined from what I can tell. So the value of this is `null` when in your widget definition it should be a function.  That is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change how you send the function or use the function.

Send the function option:

```
...
@override
void initState() {
    activeScreen = FirstScreen(() => switchScreen);
    super.initState();
}
...
```

Or use the function option:

```
...
OutlinedButton.icon(
    onPressed: () => startQuiz,
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt),
    label: const Text(
        'Start Quiz',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    ),
),
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering it is not showing error now but the screen is not changing .

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. Have you tried using Routing instead either with native flutter routing or personally i use the go_router library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved automatically after few reloads, now the same code is working fine without any error. Just reload again few times and check after each reload whether the error got vanished.